# How can I tell what recovery model my SQL database has? 

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is there a SQL command I can run to determine the recovery model of my database?  I want to know if its full recovery or not.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Some variety in how to do it...

```
SELECT D.recovery_model_desc FROM sys.databases D WHERE name = 'MyDB'
```

or

```
SELECT name, D.recovery_model_desc FROM sys.databases D
```

or

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('MyDB', 'Recovery')
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a script i made to show me database file paths and recovery models:

```
SELECT 
  A.recovery_model_desc AS [Recovery Model], 
  A.name AS [Database Name], 
  C.physical_name AS [Filename], 
  CAST(C.size * 8 / 1024.00 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Size in MB], 
  C.state_desc AS [Database State]
FROM sys.databases A
INNER JOIN sys.master_files C ON A.database_id = C.database_id
ORDER BY [Recovery Model], [Database Name], [Filename]
```

Answer (score 3):

This Query gives you the list of databases with only Simple recovery model;

```
SELECT name, DATABASEPROPERTYEX(name, 'Recovery') as Recovery_Model
FROM sys.databases
WHERE DATABASEPROPERTYEX(name, 'Recovery') = 'Simple'
ORDER BY name;
```